# Blue Prism applicaton modeler fails to identify authentication pop up window on firefox

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am trying to automate a web application using firefox on blue prism. When I use the application modeler to launch the web application, first it is asking for credentials to login on a pop up window. Application modeler cannot identify this pop up has appeared. So I cannot automate the login. However after login manually, I can spy other elements in the application as normal. Any idea on how to automate the pop up window asking for user name and password?

Comment: For anyone interested, I found a workaround:
Save the credentials on browser and then send a global key stroke of Enter after the launch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you specified your application as browser based in application modeler. It's hard to answer your question without knowing how this web application looks and works like. There are few options that you can try nevertheless:

1. In the latest version (6.4) Blue Prism introduced Firefox plug-in. If you would be able to upgrade your version to the latest one (if you are not using it already), then maybe you'll be able to spy the pop up.
2. If this web application does not necessarily need be launched via Firefox in particular, then you can test its behavior and spying possibilities on other browsers - Internet Explorer and  Google Chrome (supported by BP since 6.3 version).
3. You can spy the whole browser's window using Region mode and use Surface Automation techniques to input credentials and log in. SA functionalities are greatly improved since version 6.
4. You can try using web services (if applicable with this website) to connect with the API of the web application, you'll be able to pass/validate your credentials via web services as well. Blue Prism natively supports SOAP based web services, you might need to come with some code stages to wrap it up. It's pretty advanced stuff though and I wouldn't recommend it as a 1st choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes it's a web application. I tried all spy modes and there was no luck. However I found a workaround, save the credentials on browser and then send a global key strock of Enter. For now this way is fine for me.

Comment: Was able to identify usename and password popup box using UI Automation spy mode. Then used focus and global send keys to enter the credentials. Thanks a lot for the support.