# Using blueprism to Spy Smart Card reader

Tags: robotics, blueprism, rpa

We are implementing blue prism and have an issue to proceed.

We use the object spying for our web application which works fine. However before the application opens, we have smart card authentication. So there is a pop up for entering the smart card pin.

I am not able to detect that. Can you provide me an idea how to detect the same?

Awaiting your response.

I have tried all the Spy modes but none of it seems to work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksY7u.png)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Blue Prism version 5 or 6? There was a similar question in the past, you can look it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828516/blue-prism-applicaton-modeler-fails-to-identify-authentication-pop-up-window-on/53835593#53835593).

To sum up the options:

1. Firefox or Chrome plugins (you'll need to change object type to browser based for Firefox and Chrome) and HTML spying mode.
2. UI spying mode.
3. Use Surface Automation techniques - Region mode.
4. Web services that will use website's API (if applicable).

Options 1 & 2 are exclusive for version 6.

As for this particular problem, I would also try to create separate object for Smart Card application/pop up and treat it as separate entity (you would need to test different spying modes as well).

Hope this helps